# Why we dont have "direct" velocity operator just as $p$? ( as use $p$ space not $v$? ) in quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, velocity, observables

why there is no direct velocity operator on quantum mechanic while there is for mumentum ( $p_{x}=d/dx$ ) Also why use mumentum space not velocity?

Comment: So what is wrong with $\hat v = \frac{\hat p}{m}$?  The kinetic energy operator is also defined via the momentum operator.

Comment: No wrong, but just no use of classical form of $v$ for example.

Comment: @asaa can you shed more details on your question?

Comment: Edited, just as indirectly operator,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a speed operator in quantum mechanics, as there's a time derivative operator for all operators, using the Heisenberg equation :

\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dt}A(t)=\frac{i}{\hbar}[H,A(t)]+ \frac{\partial A}{\partial t}
\end{equation}

For speed, this will be

\begin{equation}
v = \frac{d}{dt}x=\frac{i}{\hbar}[H,x]
\end{equation}

A simple Hamiltonian is $H = \frac{p^2}{2m} + V(x)$. $x$ will commute with the potential, leaving

\begin{equation}
v = \frac{i}{\hbar2m}[p^2,x] = \frac{p}{m}
\end{equation}

which is the same relation as in classical mechanics, except with operators. A similar relation exists for $F = ma$, which is $\frac{dp}{dt} = \frac{i}{\hbar}[H,p] = -\nabla V(x)$.

Comment: except on heisenberg uncertainty principle and $Δx=<x^2>-<x>^2$ is there other place (in QM) that we see $Δx$?